# best way to generate empty 2D array

Tags: javascript, arrays

is there a shorter, better way to generate 'n' length 2D array?

```
var a = (function(){ var i=9, arr=[]; while(i--) arr.push([]); return arr })();

a // [ [],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[] ]
```

** old-school short-way**:

```
var a = (function(a){ while(a.push([]) < 9); return a})([]);
```

**UPDATE - Using ES2015**

```
Array(5).fill().map(a=>[]); // will create 5 Arrays in an Array
// or
Array.from({length:5}, a=>[])
```

**Emptying 2D array** (saves memory rather)

```
function make2dArray(len){
    var a = [];
    while(a.push([]) < len); 
    return a;
}

function empty2dArray(arr){
    for( var i = arr.length; i--; )
      arr[i].length = 0;
}

// lets make a 2D array of 3 items
var a = make2dArray(3);

// lets populate it a bit
a[2].push('demo');
console.log(a); // [[],[],["demo"]]

// clear the array
empty2dArray(a);
console.log(a); // [[],[],[]]
```

Comment: Only if you put it in a function: `var a = make2D(9);` ;)

Comment: I am using it for a web-worker which needs a 2D empty array each time it's initialized

Comment: I wonder if there is some fancy EC5 for this

Comment: Btw. shorter is not necessarily better (just wanted to point out the differences in the title and the question body ;)).

Comment: And you could make it even shorter by passing the array as parameter instead of declaring it: `var a = (function(a){ while(a.push([]) < 9); return a})([]);`

Comment: haha yeah, thats true. big fun

Comment: Or  with array **spread** syntax, your updated answer get more elegance for free: `[...Array(5)].map(()=> []); // will create 5 Arrays in an Array` :D

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Another way:

```
for(var a = [];a.length < 10; a.push([])); // semicolon is mandatory here
```

Yet another way:

```
var a = []; while(a.push([]) < 10);
```

This works because [`.push()` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) ([specification](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_15.4.4.7)) returns the new length of the array.

---

That said, this is the wrong way of "reducing code". Create a dedicated function with a meaningful name and use this one. Your code will be much more understandable:

```
function get2DArray(size) {
    size = size > 0 ? size : 0;
    var arr = [];

    while(size--) {
        arr.push([]);
    }

    return arr;
}

var a = get2DArray(9);
```

Code is read much more often than written.

Comment: @vsync: True, somehow I thought I need to compare against 10 to get 9 elements. But anyway I like 10 more :P ;)

Comment: I believe the code should be small, but very well documenter in development, and on production it's compressed anyway, so you gain better compression rate this way.

Comment: I didn't know that 'a.push([])' returns a number. this is new for me that push returns a number, this is very interesting.

Comment: @vsync: Just added it to my answer. Because it is defined like that ;)

Answer (score 8):

Just discovered another *ES6* way with one line expression:

```
Array.from({length: N}, () => [])
```

> Array.from(arrayLike[, mapFn[, thisArg]])

More detail about its implementation/polyfill ⇢ [MDN Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

Yet another neat solution with help of `array spread syntax`:

```
[...Array(N)].map(() => [])
```

Comment: Note that this is not one function call bun N + 1 because you call once Array.from() and N times `() => []` function for each iteration that happens inside Array.from.

Answer (score 3):

```
Array(cardinality).fill(0).map(function(item) {return [];});
```

where cardinality is the number of items you are looking at. In this case it would be 9. This was suggested by one of my colleagues actually. This is neat, I think :) This is valid from ECMA V6. Documentation: [Array::fill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill)

Comment: If you are using ES6, then this should be: `Array(5).fill(0).map(()=> [])`

Comment: @vsync, True that. However, you can define the prototype function yourself and use it in ECMA 5 if you want. That's what, I did for the time-being

Comment: I use Babel in my build process, so it can transforms it to ES5 automatically

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = []; for(var i=0;i<10;i++) { a[i] = []; }
```

Comment: Please post the output of `console.log(a);`. I'm curious to see whether it is the same as the OP posted. Ok, just kidding. -1 this just sets the length but it does not initialize anything.

Comment: This just sets the length, the elements are still 'undefined'

Comment: this won't create n entries with an empty array. in fact console.log return just a [].

Comment: I'm not sure why this was downvoted... it returns an empty 2D array. The output of `JSON.stringify(a)` is `"[[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]]"`.

Answer (score 0):

shorter way can be :

```
for(var i=9,a=[];i>=0;i--){ a.push([]) }
```

Comment: this is exactly the SAME as mine..yes 'for' is less characters than 'while'..but still.

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = [];
var max_length = 10;
for(var i = 0; i < max_length; ++i){ 
    a[i] = []; 
}
```

Comment: you might as well do `for(var i=9, a=[]; i--;){...` - it's better

Comment: @vsync, why is starting at nine better?

Comment: @vsync -- i added a `max_length` param.

Comment: why not? it's less code then starting with zero then adding inside the loop. it gives the same result

Comment: @vsync, not when you are using `a[i] = []` -- aalways better to start at 0

Comment: you can use `a[i]` as well in revered loop, in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var i=9,a=[];i>=0;i--){ a.push([]) }
```

Comment: hmmm..I would prefer a way which is more obvious that this is an assignment to some var..like `var 2d = ...`.

Answer (score 0):

In ES6:

```
(m, n, initialElementValue) => Array(m).fill(Array(n).fill(initialElementValue))
```

Comment: This would not create copies and would use the same array. So for example changing arr[0][1] would cause arr[1][1] and arr[2][1] to change. But it can be done [that way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47847557/6702274)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var x = 3, y = 5, arr = Array(y).fill();
arr = arr.map(function(){return Array(x).fill(' ')});
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: You answer does not provide any new information which wasn't already mentioned years ago by others here..

Answer (score 0):

best way to generate 2D array in js by ES6 by `Array.from`

```js
function twodimension(input) {
  let index = 0,
    sqrt = Math.sqrt(input.length);

  return Array.from({
    length: sqrt
  }, (nothing, i) => Array.from({
    length: sqrt
  }, (nothingTwo, j) => input[index++]))
}

console.log(twodimension('abcdefghijklmnopqrstupwxy'))
console.log(twodimension([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]))
```

```js
function input(length, fill) {
  let getNums = length * length;
  let fillNums = 1
  if (fill == 'minus') {
    return Array.from({
      length: length
    }, (nothing, i) => Array.from({
      length: length
    }, (nothingTwo, j) => getNums--))
  } else if (fill == 'plus') {
    return Array.from({
      length: length
    }, (nothing, i) => Array.from({
      length: length
    }, (nothingTwo, j) => fillNums++))
  }
  
  // you can dping snake ladders also with Array.from

  if (fill === 'snakes') {
    return Array.from({
        length: length
      }, (_, one) =>
      Array.from({
        length: length
      }, (_, two) => getNums--)
    ).map((el, i) =>
      i % 2 == 1 && length % 2 == 0 ? el.reverse() :
      i % 2 == 0 && length % 2 == 1 ? el.reverse() : el
    );
  }


}

console.log(input(8, 'minus'))
console.log(input(10, 'plus'))

console.log(input(5, 'snakes'))
```

you do anything with Array.from, it is easy to use and fast,
this is the new method in ES6 syntax