# Create Array of arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby, arrays, underscore.js

In Ruby you can make an array of arrays (which can represent a grid) by doing the following

```
@grid = Array.new(num_rows) {Array.new(num_columns)}
```

Is there an equivelent with Javascript?

Or do you need to create the first array and iterate over it, explicitly creating a new array at each index?

e.g.

```
this.grid = new Array(this.numRows);
for (var i = 0; i < this.numRows; i++) {
  this.grid[i] = new Array(this.numColumns);
}
```

I am using [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) so could leverage its methods if needs be

Comment: like `array=[[], [], []]`?

Comment: `for` loops are going to be your best bet.

Comment: yeah, I can see how to do it with a for loop, I just thought there must be a neater way, especially as I'm referencing Underscore

Comment: It wouldn't take much to make your own Constructor that would create an array of arrays. Yes, the constructor would be using a loop, but you'd only have to writ that loop once.

Comment: Ruby is an extraordinarily expressive yet concise language. Looking for equivalent ways of coding almost any Ruby idiom in another language is going to be a frustrating search.

Comment: @Borodin just curious, especially as Underscore is reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be something better in underscore, but the following will work.  I used 3 and 4 because for the height/width just so I could see the results in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lj5P9/2/).

```
array = _.map(_.range(3), function(){return _.range(4)});
```

You might want to add the underscore tag to get some underscore eyes on the question.

Comment: `_.range` already returns an array, not need to call `_.toArray`. The function should return `Array(4)` though, not `_.range(4)`.

Comment: Nice ! That makes sense. Will keep this open to see if there are any other suggestions

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript you can have different objects at different elements of an array. It's as simple as

```
var myArray = new Array()
myArray[0] = new Array()
```

You can do that as many times as you like to set up size of the 2D space you want to create. Use loops to set them up if your space is large. I don't know what objects you want in your array or I'd be more specific.

It just as easy to access this structure as in any other language: `myArray[58][12]`

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495187) is also relevant.

Comment: thanks - lets say I want a grid that's 25*50; I don't want to use your syntax to new all those arrays up. Likewise I realise I can loop over the initial array (as explained in the question). What I'm asking is if there is a more terse syntax possible, especially as I'm referencing Underscore

Comment: yes you can call `new Array(25)`, I just googled it, i was not able to find a quick 2d array creation constructor or simple syntax however, sorry about that @ChrisCa