# JavaScript: Faster way to create and initialize two dimensional array (matrix)

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is there a faster way to create and zero out a matrix?
Currently, my code involves two for loops:

```
var nodes = new Array(ast.length);

for (var i=0; i < nodes.length; i++){
    nodes[i] = new Array(ast.length);
    for (var j=0; j < nodes.length; j++)
        nodes[i][j]=0;
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of - http://stackoverflow.com/q/6495187/104380

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you asked for "faster", it looks like you can gain some speed by creating a single initalized array and then using `.slice()` to copy it rather than initializing each array itself:

```
var nodes = new Array(ast.length);
var copy = new Array(ast.length);
for (var i = 0; i < ast.length; i++) {
    copy[i] = 0;
}

for (var i=0; i < nodes.length; i++){
    nodes[i] = copy.slice(0);
}
```

jsperf test: http://jsperf.com/slice-vs-for-two-d-array/2

This method looks to be 10-20% faster in all three major browsers.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You could use the [Array.prototype.fill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) method:

```
var nodes = Array(ast.length).fill(Array(ast.length).fill(0));
```

jsperf test: http://jsperf.com/fill-array-matrix

Comment: Note fill() is not fully supported.

Comment: I think this will also be slower than the OPs code, but it is comparable.

Comment: Note to OP: `.fill()` is not universally supported yet.  There appears to be no support in IE or iOS7 and not great support in Android.  You could use a polyfill, but don't expect the polyfill to be fast.  So, basically this could speed you up in Chrome, Firefox and Edge.

Comment: No doubt it is fast in initializing, the problem with this approach is, if I decide to change a single cell value, lets say nodes[0][4] = 1, it will change the 4th column to 1 for all the rows.

Comment: What SaadH said happens to me too.  Seems like a very counter-intuitive side effect.

Comment: This needs to be downvoted more.  It's incorrect to have identical rows.

Answer (score 3):

You can create array of zeros once and create copies of it:

```
var length = 10;

var zeros = Array.apply(null, Array(length)).map(Number.prototype.valueOf, 0);
var nodes = zeros.map(function(i) {
    return zeros.slice();
});

console.log(nodes);
```

Comment: Your code shows a length of 10, but you claim 1000x1000.  I think you need to publish your measurement technique to believe array fill is 0ms and your solution is 4ms vs. 1492ms for the double `for` loop.  That seems like too much difference to me to be right.  If so, great.  But, without more documentation, it's a bit hard to believe.

Comment: Thanks. Your solution's and @jfriend00 's running times are almost same.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how fast this is in terms of producing a 2d array but it is IMHO a better way that most.

```
Array.prototype.dim = function(){
    if( this.length==2 ){
        r=this.shift(); c=this.shift();
        while( r-- ) this.push( new Array( c ).fill(0,0) );
        return this;
    }
}
```

In use, the 2d array is made by initialising a regular 1d array with the parameters of x,y or rows, cols as two parameters. These are then used to dimension the array and fill it with zeros at the same time.

```
var arr = new Array(5,7).dim();
console.log(arr[4]);
```

The array then has got the desired dimension with zeros.

The output:

```
console.log(arr[4]);
 (7) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

I hope someone finds this useful.