# Create an array of arrays, in which every array has 10 random numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays, arrayofarrays

Here I try to understand how to create array of arrays: I created one array but  how to create  an array of arrays, in which every array has 10 random numbers?

```
var arrRand = [];
    while(arrRand.length < 10){
        var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
        if(arrRand.indexOf(random) === -1) arrRand.push(random);
    }
    console.log(arrRand);
```

Comment: Already have plenty of answers here on stackoverflow for such questions, break it down into 2 questions and google it

Comment: [best way to generate empty 2D array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6495187/104380)

Comment: [Creating array of length n with random numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34966459/104380)

Comment: `Array(4).fill( Array(10).fill( Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)) )` it will be 4 x 10 array of random numbers

Comment: @Leonardo Your solution would be great if it wouldn't use the same number to fill the arrays.

Comment: @NiklasE. good point  ; btw see how people copy paste this inaccurate comment into answers

Answer (score 2):

A functional approach with every number being random.

```js
let x = Array(4).fill().map(
  () => Array(10).fill().map(
    () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)
  )
);

console.log(x);
```

Comment: yeah this works; the outter .map() can be safely omitted by the way; I'd tested it in browser console

Comment: @Leonardo Elaborate. The way I see it,  the outer map function is necessary and cannot be omitted. Otherwise it would be the same array four times.

Comment: yeah both maps are necessary; +1

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Math.random` and a nested `for loop`. Here is an example:

```js
let arr = [];
for(let i = 0; i < 4; i++){
     let current = [];
     for(let j = 0; j < 10; j++)
          current.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10));
     arr.push(current);
}
console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to keep clean and dry code, you can use ***map*** function in ES6 syntax.

```js
 const x = [...Array(6)].map(
    () => [...Array(10)].map(
        () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1
    )
 )

console.log(x)
```

Comment: Interesting how you're using `[...Array(10)]` instead of `Array(10).fill()` to make them mappable, but that's not better actually: It only saves 2 characters and it is less efficient, because the interpreter would initialize two arrays, iterating through the inner to generate the outer. I would stick to my answer.

Comment: `[...Array(6)]` is useless redundant version of `Array(6)`

Comment: @NiklasE. yeah; correct; it's not. btw I'm seeing people mindlessly over-using the spared syntax everywhere; not here btw; it's legit. but I prefer Array.fill()

Comment: By using spread syntax, the code is more consistent and clear because we can notice easily ```[...Array(6)]``` as it is an array in the map function. Not a big deal with the code performance but it brings a clean code and intuitive sense.

Answer (score -1):

```
let a = Array(4).fill(Array(10).fill(null))
```

Then fill it with `Math.random()` in loop

Comment: Only half an answer. And unnecessary if the missing part can be done together with the first.